# How to perform certain actions only when the file is called from the command line

Tags: php

I have a php file that contains class which runs some lengthy database operations. The file is included in a few other scripts, but I would like to be able to call the file from the command line either in another program or as part of a crontab so that it can run in the background for longer processes.

Is there a way to detect that the file is being called from the command line so I can run a function that will instantiate the object and execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [php_sapi_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to determine what interface PHP is using. This will return 'cli' if it is the command line, and a specific name string if anything else.

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  echo 'Executing from the command line';
} else {
  echo 'Likely executing via a web server';
}
```